# Compare Robotium and AndroidDriver?

Tags: robotium

How would you compare Robotium and AndroidDriver tool for mobile application testing?
Can anyone explain me the detailed statistics?

Answer (score 0):

I have use android driver of the appium testing.

Robotium can test both blackbox and white box.

AndroidDriver is for blackbox testing, which means that if you want to assert the activity, you cannot do with it.

Robotium is a very powerful tool, and the biggest problem is the cross process.

Answer (score 0):

This is very broad question but I will talk about three aspects:
Type of applications, different OS and different development languages.
I would discuss [appium](http://appium.io/) as implementation for the WebDriver (Selenium).

1. Usually we are consider three types of the mobile apps - native, hybrid and web apps. Robotium provides a good support for the native application. Robotium 4.0 supports hybrid application. Appium provides in addition a good support for the mobile web application. Especially I would recommend appium if you have to test a web application on other platforms (Linux, Windows). In this case you may use almost the same code.
2. We use Robotium for the Android devices only. You may use appium for the different OS like iOS.
3. One of the biggest advantages of Appium is that you can write your Appium code on many programming language (e.g. Java, Objective-C, JavaScript, PHP, Ruby, Python or C#, etc)

To summarize: use Robotium in case you need write tests fast and you are interesting in the Android app only. Use appium if you need wide device/OS supporting and Java not your prefered language,